# putRecord in stream fails to find firehose

Tags: scala, amazon-kinesis-firehose

So I am trying to implement

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javav2-firehose-src-main-java-com-example-firehose-PutRecord.java.html

but when I copy over the imports, it never finds firehose.  As you can see in the picture, the awssdk is available, just not the firehose portion.  Anyone know where this should be properly referenced?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did find the answer on this.  In the file menu in IntelliJ, there is "Invalidate Caches".  Clear them and reinstall, and the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the firehose dependency to your project.

If you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
   <artifactId>firehose</artifactId>
   <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```